# Wall time and cpu time in Linux command time

Tags: linux, time

When I use Linux `time` command to measure time spent for running a command, which one below corresponds to CPU time and wall time?

```
real    3m13.792s
user    9m35.958s
sys 0m41.066s
```

Comment: Did you read the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time)? Anyway, this is not a programming question and is thus off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which one below corresponds to CPU time

`user` is cpu time in user mode, `sys` is cpu time in kernel mode

> and wall time?

`real`

Comment: In the case above, wall (real) time is bigger than cpu time (user or sys). Normal?

Comment: When __two__ CPUs work for one second, how much cpu time was spent?